# How to combine limits when integrating in the frequency domain

Tags: optics, integration

I want to combine the signal of two separate pulses in the frequency domain in order to calculate their overlap (by multiplying the two signals together and integrating). However, one of these signals is a rectangular pulse with a finite bandwidth, while the other has a sech lineshape and therefore an infinite bandwidth. I'm confused about what happens to the limits of my system when I combine the two. Is it just that I take the limits of the finite bandwidth pulse because there will be no overlap outside this range? How would one represent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $R(\omega)$ is the rectangular pulse, centred at $\omega_R$, and defined
$$
R(\omega) = \begin{cases} R_0 & \omega_R-\Delta < \omega < \omega_R+\Delta \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
and $S(\omega)$ is the sech lineshape, centred at $\omega_S$, something like
$$
S(\omega) = S_0 \, \text{sech}\left(\frac{\omega-\omega_S}{W}\right)
$$
then
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\omega \, R(\omega)S(\omega) &= 
R_0S_0\int_{\omega_R-\Delta}^{\omega_R+\Delta} d\omega \, 
\text{sech}\left(\frac{\omega-\omega_S}{W}\right) 
\\ &= 
R_0S_0\int_{-\Delta}^{\Delta} d\omega \, 
\text{sech}\left(\frac{\omega+\omega_R-\omega_S}{W}\right)
\\ &=
R_0S_0\int_{\omega_R-\omega_S-\Delta}^{\omega_R-\omega_S+\Delta} d\omega \, 
\text{sech}\left(\frac{\omega}{W}\right)
\end{align*}
where I've simply written three equivalent versions of the result,
by shifting the integration variable.

EDIT
The answer above now includes the width of the sech function, $W$.

Also, the integral of the $\text{sech}\omega$ function is exactly known,
$$
\tan^{-1}(\sinh \omega) + \text{constant}
$$
so the final result may be expressed
$$
WR_0S_0\left\{
\tan^{-1}\left[\sinh \left(\frac{\omega_R-\omega_S+\Delta}{W}\right)\right]
-
\tan^{-1}\left[\sinh \left(\frac{\omega_R-\omega_S-\Delta}{W}\right)\right]
\right\}
$$

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Is the result of this integral the overlap or do I need to calculate the absolute square?

Comment: I only wrote it this way because your question says "multiplying the signals together and integrating". I think you will have to work out for yourself, from the underlying physics, whether you need to calculate the absolute square. It shouldn't affect the issue with the limits of integration. Also, squaring the rectangular pulse just gives you another rectangular pulse.

Comment: I've added a couple of details to make the answer clearer, hopefully. Let me know if anything more is needed.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. The full system is a distribution of nuclear spins that each has a linewidth of 10kHz that each have some overlap with the pulse, which has a linewidth of 5MHz and area of `\pi/2`. I think the pulse can be modeled using `S_0=1/4` and `W=2`, as modeling and plotting this gives a pulse that has the correct linewidth and area. I believe the value of `R_0` is 1 and the overlap is found taking the absolute square of the two systems multiplied together. If there seems to be anything completely wrong with this please let me know!

Comment: Unfortunately I am not knowledgeable enough on spin resonance that I feel able to comment! Perhaps you can frame a question on this, explaining more of the physics, that might attract answers from experts. I suggest that you either edit your other question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/434063/integrating-rectangular-functions-to-calculate-pulse-overlap to focus more on this than on the issue of integration limits, or delete that question and perhaps come back later with a new one.